# How can i adjust this hover style?

Tags: css

I wanna adjust this hover style that I have attached below.
https://clay.global/
In the footer of this website, when you hover on items, you can see a half-background and pink color on it. I appreciate it if you can help me and say what CSS style shall I use.Thanks
https://clay.global/

[image]

Comment: Post your comment in the question, [don't just link to it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The easiest way to do that is to use a Stack Snippet (icon looks like [<>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) in the toolbar).

Comment: you're using `::before` - just edit that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to highlight just the bottom half of an element is to set a background image linear-gradient with the top half transparent and the bottom half some color.

For example:

```css
button:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0 50%, pink 50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<button>business set</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For an HTML like:

```
<p>Text to highlight</p>
```

CSS could be sth like:

```
p {
  position: relative; /*must be relative or absolute */
  display: inline; /* must be inline for ::after to be the same width as p */
}
p::after {
  background: pink;
  content: ""; /* content must be here for it to show up*/
  position: absolute; /*must be absolute to be positionied over p*/
  z-index: -1; /* put it behind the text*/
  width: 104%; /* set the highgligth a bit thicker*/
  left: -2%; /* set the highlight left proporcionally to the width*/
  bottom: -4%; /* set the position offset respect to the text*/
  height: 0.5em; /* set the height difference respect to the text*/
}
```